# How to implement gateway in java

Tags: http, httprequest, gateway, forward

I have to implement a Gateway in java.
I have a servlet that recieves information like the URL to hit and parameters to be passed to that URL.
I need to get the response back from there, make some modifications, if required, and pass it back to the browser.

I tried opening a HttpConnection to the URL and then simply writing on its outputstream but as i guessed thats not working. Is it possible to create a new HttpRequest and execute it?
How can i implement this in java? It looks like Apache httpclient is one of the options but i am not supposed to use that or any other external library as such.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Vivek

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a [java.net.Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and [java.net.ServerSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). With ServerSocket, you can listen to a specific port waiting connections/requests and with Socket you can send the requested client data and sends to the original server. It's a base to build your own gateway project...